# .strftime doesn't apply zero padding on '%Y' in python:3.7-slim Docker image

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I found a strange quirk in the slim version of the python Docker image with regards to date formatting. If you pass it a first-century date, `%Y-%m-%d` formatting doesn’t yield a zero-padded year-part:

```
$ docker run -ti python:3.7-slim /bin/bash
root@71f21d562837:/# python
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov 23 2019, 06:10:46) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import date
>>> d = date(197,1,1)
>>> d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'197-01-01'
```

But running this on the same python version locally on my macbook does yield 4 digits for the year:

```
$ python                     
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  1 2019, 02:16:32) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import date
>>> d = date(197,1,1)
>>> d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'0197-01-01'
```

The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) suggest that `%y` should yield no zero padding while `%Y` should.

Same quirk for version 3.6-slim.
The problem with this is that some systems (like BigQuery) requires the zero padding.

What would be the most elegant/least hacky workaround for this? I'm building a custom image derived from python:3.7-slim. I'm open to using a different image with a small footprint, or making an elegant code change.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a manual workaround to get identical formatting on all platforms:

```
from datetime import date
d = date(197,1,1)
dstr = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
dstr = ('0'+dstr if len(dstr.split('-')[0]) == 3 else dstr)
print(dstr)
```

Comment: This is a promising path since we avoid the quirks altogether. What would you do if the year can be any amount of digits from 1 to 4? Like for example 8-1-1.

Comment: How about this? ```"%04d" % d.year + d.strftime("-%m-%d")```